# Parse IRC PRIVMSG in C

Tags: c, parsing, irc

I am quite new to C (I am more used to C++) and I am trying to create an IRC Bot. I am currently struggling to find the correct string parsing functions to parse this line:

```
:nick!~username@server PRIVMSG #channel :message (could contain the word PRIVMSG)
```

So, I am asking if anyone could show me what functions I would use to split up this line into:

- nick
- username
- server
- channel
- message

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the message body contains the word "PRIVMSG" or not: everything after the colon is considered to be the message body, ending after at most 512 bytes with "\r\n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use sscanf. Something on this general order seems to be a reasonable starting point:

```
char nick[32], user[32], server[32], channel[32], body[256];

sscanf(buffer, ":%31[^!]!~%31[^@]@%31s PRIVMSG #%31s :%255[^\n]", 
                 nick,     user, server,       channel, body);
```

Comment: first arg to sscanf is the buffer to be parsed, the second arg is the template string...

Comment: The length of the nickname, user, hostname, channel and content can change based on the server, this might not be the best method.

Comment: Right, the only length mentioned in the spec is the total message size: 510 bytes plus a CRLF. Relying on these lengths is bound to cause issues.

Comment: @Pygmalion: Yes, that's the difference between "something on this general order seems to be a reasonable starting point", and "here's finished code". But yes, the spec (RFC 1459, since you're apparently unaware of it) does specify maximum lengths.

Comment: It does? Where? I've read the spec (I'm working on an IRC server right now) and don't see any mention of it. And in case you aren't aware, RFC 2812 updated RFC 1459 in 2000. Edit: Actually I see that nicks have a 9 character limit and hosts have a 63 character limit (max length of a hostname on the broader Internet).

Comment: RFC 1459 says channel names are limited to 200 characters (section 1.3). That leaves only the `name` that we don't know a maximum length with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that all this is in a char[] buffer that you can write onto (i.e., the contents will be overwritten), you can do something like:

```
char *nick, *username, *server, *command, *channel, *message;

nick     = strtok(buffer+1, "!");
username = strtok(NULL, "@");
server   = strtok(NULL, " ");
command  = strtok(NULL, " ");
channel  = strtok(NULL, " ");
message  = strtok(NULL, "");
```

You need to add some error checking to the above code, since any call to strtok() may return NULL if no more tokens are found. You could also use some more elaborate parsing, or sscanf().

Read the pages about [strtok(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) and [sscanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: It should be noted that `strtok()` destroys the input string after its use. Should be taken something into consideration.